# Кастомный вывод ошибок/предупреждений/информации битрикс24 коробка

Tags: php, битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно есть какой-то вариант реализации вывода ошибок или предупреждений в коробке битрикса, как пример при сохранении контакта вывод на экран изображения или же окна с информацией?